# The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

New to C# and I don't know why I can't get this working

I have tried removing the parts that I have added when the code came but nothing.

Errors:

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has
>   some invalid arguments Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'char[]'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Metode_test
{
    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] udsagnsord = new string[] { "kan", "lide" };
        string[] navneord = new string[] { "kage" };
        string[] egenavne = new string[] { "Andreas" };

        string s = "Andreas kan lide kage";
        string[] words = s.Split( ' ' );


        foreach (string word in words)
        {

            Console.Write(word);

            foreach (string verbum in udsagnsord) 
            {

                if ( word == verbum ) 
                {
                    Console.Write(" (");
                }

            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}



}
```

Comment: i don't think you are giving us the full error.

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. You probably had `" "` instead of `' '` in the original code or something like that. They're not interchangeable in C#, `"` denotes a `string` literal, while `'` denotes a `char` literal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not your actual code.According to error message you are trying to pass a string delimiter to `Split` method. There is no overload that takes `params string[]` but you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want.

```
public string[] Split(
    string[] separator,
    StringSplitOptions options
)
```

Or you can create an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static string[] Split(this string source, params string[] delimiters)
{
     return source.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
str.Split("separator1","separator2");
```

**Note:** If you don't want to use a `string` as delimiter, but a char, you need to use *single quotes*,  *double quotes* are used to represent `strings`.